# Handling custom exceptions (i18n) with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4 with Spring JPA, Spring Data REST, HATEOAS...
I'm looking for a best practice (Spring way) to customize exceptions Spring Data REST is managing adding the i18n support.

I looked at the class MessageException (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/support/ExceptionMessage.java) as start point.

A typical Spring Data REST exception is very nice:

```
    {
    "timestamp": "2017-06-24T16:08:54.107+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
    "message": "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved beforeQuery current operation : com.test.server.model.workflows.WorkSession.checkPoint -> com.test.server.model.checkpoints.CheckPoint; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved beforeQuery current operation : com.test.server.model.workflows.WorkSession.checkPoint -> com.test.server.model.checkpoints.CheckPoint",
    "path": "/api/v1/workSessions/start"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Localize error and message fields (i18n)
2. possibly change the message text to something else (always localized)

I didn't find any reference in Spring Data REST doc about how to customize or localize exception (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/).
I hope there is a elegant way to do that.

I added in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter this:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new SmartLocaleResolver();
}

public class SmartLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if (acceptLanguage == null || acceptLanguage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return super.determineDefaultLocale(request);
        }
        return request.getLocale();
    }

}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("i18n/messages"); // name of the resource bundle
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return source;
}
```

I guess I could be able to intercept exceptions in this way:

```
    @ControllerAdvice(annotations = RepositoryRestController.class)
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity handle(Exception e, Locale locale) {
          //missing part...
            return new ResponseEntity(exceptionMessageObject, new HttpHeaders(), httpStatus);
    }
```

Is there a way to put all together using Spring best practices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RepositoryRestController.class)
public class GenericExceptionHandler {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler
    //if you don't use Exception e in method you can remove it , live only Locale
    public ResponseEntity handle(Exception e, Locale locale) {

            String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(
                                 "error.message", new Object[]{},locale);  
            //set message  or return it instead of exceptionMessageObject
            exceptionMessageObject.setMessage(exceptionMessageObject);

            return new ResponseEntity(exceptionMessageObject, 
                   new HttpHeaders(), httpStatus);
    }
```

see spring doc [7.15.1 Internationalization using MessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource)

---

> " how I should create exceptionMessageObject to be like the one Spring
>   Data REST creates? "

create you own error wraper like :

```
public class CustomError {
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private Exception originalException;//if you need it        
    // getter setter
}
```

> "How to have different messages for different exceptions? Should I
>   create a long if else chain checking the class of the exception? "

create resolver ,

```
private String resolveExceptionToMessage(Exception exceptio){
    //or put in map<Exceptio,String error.message.type1> 
    // String errorCode = map.get(excptio);
    //eturn messageSource.getMessage(errorCode , new Object[]{},locale);
    if(exceptio instanceof ....){
        return messageSource.getMessage("error.message.type1", new Object[]{},locale);
    }
    return "";
}
```

or use methods with @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class }) , @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class }).... and do put in each method just errror.code , all other part are similar

```
 @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleException1() {
        return createError(code for this exceptio 1);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException2.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleException2() {
        return createError(code for this exceptio 2);
    }
    private ResponseEntity createError(String errorCode ) {
            CustomError customError = new CustomError();
            customError.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(
                                 errorCode , new Object[]{},locale); 

            customError.setMessage(errorMessage );
            customError.setOriginalException(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(customError, new HttpHeaders(), 
                          customError.getStatus());
    }
```

> How set httpStatus? I would like use the default status Spring Data
>   REST use for commons exceptions...

```
public ResponseEntity handle(Exception e, Locale locale) {
        CustomError customError = new CustomError();
        customError.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        customError.setMessage(resolveExceptionToMessage(e));
        customError.setOriginalException(e);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(customError, new HttpHeaders(), 
                      customError.getStatus());
}
```

Comment: how I should create exceptionMessageObject to be like the one Spring Data REST creates? How to have different messages for different exceptions? Should I create a long if else chain checking the class of the exception? How set httpStatus? I would like use the default status Spring Data REST use for commons exceptions...thanks

Comment: I didn't know that you don't have base stuff for return new ResponseEntity(exceptionMessageObject, new HttpHeaders(), httpStatus); .I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I marked that as answer. I posted another way to do this, customizing ErrorAttributes, that in my opinion is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sbjavateam for his reply. I want to post another way to do this thing just for completeness. The comment is not ideal to write everything, so I'm replying here.

Instead to use a @ControllerAdvice, a simpler solution is customize the ErrorAttributes:

```
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
        Throwable throwable = getError(requestAttributes);

        /**
         * Adding the cause if present
         */
        if (throwable != null && throwable.getCause() != null) {
            Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
            Map<String, Object> causeErrorAttributes = new HashMap<>();
            causeErrorAttributes.put("exception", cause.getClass().getName());
            causeErrorAttributes.put("message", cause.getMessage());
            errorAttributes.put("cause", causeErrorAttributes);
        }

        /**
         * Customizing the message for every exception
         */
        if (throwable instanceof InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException) {
            String message = messageSource.getMessage(throwable.getClass().getName(), new Object[] {}, locale);
            errorAttributes.put("message", message);
        }
        return errorAttributes;
    }
}
```

Of course you have to define this bean in your WebMvcConfigurerAdapter or add the @Component. In the first case you need to do:

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = { HypermediaType.HAL })
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CustomErrorAttributes myCustomErrorAttributes() {
        return new CustomErrorAttributes();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

In this way is very easy customize the exception and you can just override values rather than create a new custom exception object.

Comment: you should be sure that throwable.getClass().getName() in message file.

Comment: Of course, that is my project decision. I also use messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true); so the message is not translated if not found.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use CustomErrorController. This controller caches all errors including 404.
Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${error.path:/error}")
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

@Value("${error.path:/error}")
private String errorPath;

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return this.errorPath;
}

@RequestMapping
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // your code here...
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, status);
}
}
```